# Message "cross-database references are not implemented" for a simple query from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

I need to query PostgreSQL from SQL Server. I created a linked server connection (ODBC for PostgreSQL, the newest). It works on some schemas and not on the others. They're all on the same server.

For example this works:

```
SELECT * FROM LinkedPS.MyDatabase.Schema1.Table1
```

and this doesn't:

```
SELECT * FROM LinkedPS.MyDatabase.Schema2.Table2
```

I wasn't able to find any property which would cause this.

Comment: Are these really all tables, and not, say, views with some shenanigans going on? Does `EXECUTE ('SELECT * FROM Schema2.Table2') AT LinkedPS` work?

Comment: Yes, it does. I was told by the admin of PostgreSQL that these are all normal tables. The viewes my first idea.

Comment: You probably need to establish a separate link for each PostgreSQL database you want to talk to, even if they all reside on the same PostgreSQL server.  One connection is not able to access data from multiple PostgreSQL databases.

Comment: It's the same database.